# Jquery: show and hide portlets

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to show/hide my portlet and nothing happen :(
http://plnkr.co/edit/1rjq3UzJ6NYaDU2mNS2O?p=preview

```
$("#add").click(function() {
  $("#porlet1 portlet-body").hide();  
  $("#porlet1").hide();
  $("#porlet2").show();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#porlet2 portlet-body").show();
  }, 100);
});

$("#remove").click(function() {
  $("#porlet2 portlet-body").hide();
  $("#porlet2").hide();
  $("#porlet1").show();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#porlet1 portlet-body").show();
  }, 100);
});
```

In my real project porlet1 hides and portlet2 shows. After 2nd hiding the 1st appears and then I click to show the 2nd and all porlets hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your js code..  in Your code  typo mistakes are there. id's speling are incorrect

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add").click(function() {

   $("#portlet1 .portlet-body").hide();
  $("#portlet1").hide();
  $("#portlet2").show();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#portlet2 .portlet-body").show();
  }, 100);
});

$("#remove").click(function() {
  $("#portlet2 .portlet-body").hide();
  $("#portlet2").hide();
  $("#portlet1").show();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#portlet1 .portlet-body").show();
  }, 100);
});
})
```

Comment: Thanks, updated my plunk. But I see when I click button second and more times my portlet body don't show with timeout :(

Comment: Plese use my updated code i missed '.' before portlet-body  $("#portlet1 .portlet-body").hide();